# Where is the equivalent of setConverter in the ListView Control like a ComBox Control?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

The ComboBox control has a setConverter method, see [JavaFX ComboBox - Display text but return ID on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634789/javafx-combobox-display-text-but-return-id-on-selection) for an example. I am trying to adapt the accepted answer from that question to work with a ListView control. I don't see a setConverter method for the ListView class in any documentation.

```
@FXML   private ListView<RowlvPqAttributes>  lvPqAttributes;
//...
    class RowlvPqAttributes {
        private String ID;
        private String text;
        public RowlvPqAttributes(String ID, String text) {
            setID(ID);
            setText(text);
        }
        public String getID() {
            return ID;
        }
        public void setID(String iD) {
            ID = iD;
        }
        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }
        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }
    private void initlvPqAttributes() {
        lvPqAttributes.setConverter(new StringConverter<RowlvPqAttributes>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(RowlvPqAttributes object) {
                return object.getText();
            }

            @Override
            public RowlvPqAttributes fromString(String string) {
                return lvPqAttributes.getItems().stream().filter(ap -> 
                    ap.getText().equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
            }   
        });
```

[image: Here is the compile error I get]

If I accept the suggested fix it doesn't help:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do not work in the same way, for the `ListView` you configure the display using `setCellFactory` method

```
lvPqAttributes.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<RowlvPqAttributes>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(RowlvPqAttributes row, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(row, empty) ;
        setText(empty ? null : row.getText());
    }
}
```

For getting data from selected item:

```
RowlvPqAttributes selected = lvPqAttributes.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
String selectedID = selected.getID();
String selectedText = selected.getText();
```

Comment: Thanks! Fantastic answer.